# SAS- Decomposition Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sas

What is SAS decomposition algorithm. [SAS documentation for decomposition algorithm](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/or/132/decomp.pdf). I don't understand this and can someone please explain it in simple terms? Can I use that algorithm to solve ATM optimization problem as explained [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/68156/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_decomp_examples13.htm) and how optimal is the solution? Are there any better algorithms to solve this ATM optimization problem?

Comment: This is a deep topic and you should not expect to be able to understand it all quickly or easily. I suggest you start by doing some basic research on mixed-integer linear programming.

Comment: This is not SAS-specific, but an overall optimization problem. You will need to do a lot of research to understand it. SAS implements the decomposition algorithm and provides automatic detection for if the problem is decomposable. I really like the decomposition method for MILPs, as it can have huge performance benefits. If you can use that route, I would recommend it. If you have questions implementing it with OPTMODEL, we can answer that, but this is more theoretical.

Comment: What I tried was to use a dynamic programming approach ( as explained in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309285.pdf)  using heuristics to avoid the costly combinations. But I'm still struck with finding a heuristic approach to avoid costly combinations, so that computation time will be minimized. I already added the question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359719/algorithm-to-avoid-obvious-costly-combinations-when-splitting-n-values-to-m-grou

Comment: Any suggestion to this issue will be really helpful.