# Algorithm to avoid obvious costly combinations when splitting n values to m groups

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, heuristics, np, simulated-annealing

I have 7 values and I need to split them into 5 groups. Each group should contain atleast one value. There are 15 ways to group those values into 5.

Mon- 13
Tue- 5
Wed- 4
Thu- 4
Fri- 11
Sat- 2
Sun- 1

When grouping, ordering of Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun should be preserved.

Suppose there is a function which decides how good a grouping is.

13, 5, 4, 4, 11, 2, 1

**Function**

Grouping 1 - 13, 5, [4,4], 11, [2,1]

13 added, 13 withdrawn, 0 remaining

5 added, 5 withdrawn, 0 remaining

[4,4] added, 4 withdrawn, 4 remaining

0 added, 4 withdrawn, 0 remaining

11 added, 11 withdrawn, 0 remaining

[2, 1] added, 2 withdrawn, 1 remaining

0 added, 1 withdrawn, 0 remaining

cost = sum of remainings at the end of the day = 4+1 = 5

I need to find the grouping with minimum cost. Is there a way(eg: heuristic approach) to avoid obvious costly combinations, so that I don't have to try all the groupings to find the grouping with minimum cost?

**Example for obvious costly combination**

13, [5,4], [4,11], 2, 1

Larger the sum remaining at the end of the day, costlier the grouping is

**Actual prediction data for 2 weeks**

[prediction data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8LGU.png)

Comment: Is n/m perhaps small? I feel like it would be a much easier problem, if the average group size was somehow limited.

Comment: n= 7 but m can be 5,3 or 1. It would be enough if this can be solved for at least one value of m. So yeah please consider n to be 7 and m to be 5.

Comment: The ordering Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun should be preserved. Example - 13, [5,4,4], 11, 2, 1 correct. But not 13, [5,4,4], 2, 11, 1

Comment: If n is always just 7, i think just trying out combinations is pretty reasonable. A proper algorithm might be even worse for such small inputs. Perhaps you can rule out the combinations where the largest number is at the end of the largest group :). Or if a higher than average value is at the end of the largest group maybe?

Comment: Even when the order is preserved, for each grouping of 7 into 3 and 7 into 5, there are 15 combinations. So totally 30 combinations for each week. And for a month it's 30*4=120 combinations. Isn't it gonna consume much time if I do it that way?

Comment: You aren't doing that manually, are you? If you write a program, this is a very small amount.

Comment: To find the cost of each grouping, I'm going to use a dynamic approach as explained here [https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309285.pdf ]. It has a  O(N^2) time complexity. So I thought it might slow down performance, if I compute this cost for every grouping.

Comment: To calculate the cost, can't you just take in each [ a, b, c, d ...], the cost = 0*a + 1*b + 2*c + 3*d + ..., because d will be remaining 3 times, c will be 2 times and so on. I assumed they are withdrawn in order like that. First a, then b, then c...

Comment: okay I got it.  I still wish if I could optimize this using some heuristics :D

Comment: Glad to help :) I would suggest some heuristic to optimize it, if i could think of any, but i'm afraid that this might be a really difficult problem for the general case of n being large and m anything smaller than n. Then it might end up so that you spend a few days trying to solve it and then the end result is still slower  in practice than trying out all combinations :D for such a small n.

Comment: Trying all the combinations is extremely cheap, there is no sense to try to optimize it without further details of what will you use it for.

Comment: This is used for ATM optimization. 7 values are the daily cash deposits to the ATM. What I calculated as the cost is total holding cost for a particular week. I'm going to group 7 values into 5,3, or 1 because cash can only be deposited in 5 days, 3 days or 1 days.